# how do i filter json with a url in browser?

Tags: json

If I had a theoretical URL with the following JSON data returned at http://colors.com

Using google chrome, how could I form the URL so that I only retrieve the color "red"? Is it possible to use logic in the URL to filter multiple items? Example: color "red" AND value "#f00"

Does it depend on what's running on the webserver? If it does, what information would I need to find out how to form the query?

```
[
{
    color: "red",
    value: "#f00"
},
{
    color: "green",
    value: "#0f0"
},
{
    color: "blue",
    value: "#00f"
},
{
    color: "cyan",
    value: "#0ff"
},
{
    color: "magenta",
    value: "#f0f"
},
{
    color: "yellow",
    value: "#ff0"
},
{
    color: "black",
    value: "#000"
}
]
```

Comment: Yes it depends what the script at colors.com does, it would need to have been written to allow you to do what you want (return a subset), the only way to know that is to read any API documentation/ask the developer.  The other alternative is to just ignore the data you don't want within your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is up to the server to offer an API to filter the colors. In the URL you cannot do nothing if the server does not implement this functionality. In case it is implemented you could make a request like:

```js
GET /colors?color="red"
```

In others cases, you will have to filter the response at the client side:

```js
red = colors.filter(x => { return x.color == "red"})
console.log(red[0])
```

Hope it helps!